# Is it possible to add a global event (keyup.enter) to all forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

imagine a situation where I have 1000 forms in 1000 components..

Classic form:

```
<form (submit)="submitForm()" >
  <input type="text"> 
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

I need to go thought all components and add on every component **keyup.enter**:

```
<form (submit)="submitForm()" (keyup.enter)="submitForm()">
  <input type="text"> 
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Does anyone have any solution how to do this in the easiest way without putting keyup.enter on each component ?

I googled something first for example

```
(submit.enter)="submitForm()"
```

but this is no exist.

Also i am try with directive but no success...
any idea?

Comment: First, why would you want to submit every form? Otherwise, in straight javascript, you can set a listener for the keyup event on the document, or just on the form elements collection, if it's enter then get the form ID from the event and submit it.

Comment: ngSubmit also works on enter but only when the field is active on the input ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive that selects the form element, and add a HostListener to the element:

```js
@Directive({ selector: 'form' })
export class MyFormDirective {

  constructor(
    private readonly el: ElementRef<HTMLFormElement>
  ) { }

  @HostListener('keyup.enter', ['$event'])
  onFormKeyUp(evt: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.el.nativeElement.submit();
  }
}
```

View the working example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k8hofz)

Comment: i set this up but it doesn't work. i just made a directive and added this code? Do I need to adjust something inside the component itself and the template?

Comment: can you help me about this ? my function is not triggered ? WHy ? what happened ?

Comment: are you here ? Can you hel me ? it's not working for me right now .... I don't know why. It does not trigger ? do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Did you add it to your app's module?

Comment: @yajoj98337 I have added a working example to the answer.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Why is refresh page after hit enter ? What happened

Comment: Because that is how a form submit works. If you want to call a function on the component then you need to call that function instead.